# vCenter - Unable to get deployment status

Tags: vcenter

Is there a way to restart the vcenter installation without having to re-install?

There are a couple of service issue which can be fixed manually. But I need the vCenter to restart the installation, instead of re-install because it fails again and I have to fix the services manually again.

If I can restart the installation, then the installation may succeed as I've fixed the service issues. Re-install doesn't work.

I'm trying to figure out how I can restart the installation. I get the following error right now.

[image]

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue. this solution doesn't help me

Answer (score 0):

The post
[VCSA 7.0.2 Upgrade Installer - Stage 2 Export Partition](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-vCenter-Discussions/VCSA-7-0-2-Upgrade-Installer-Stage-2-Export-Partition/td-p/2835625)
seems to address the same problem.

The solution was :

> After Stage 1 is done, close the installer and open the VAMI interface on the new deployment of vCSA: `https://<IP>:5480/configure/`. You can now do the Stage 2 from your browser, and set a export directory that is big enough (for instance `/storage/updatemgr/`)
>
> Apparently the installer is using a "v2" of the configuration (`https://<IP>:5480/configurev2/`) where the export directory can't be set.

Answer (score -1):

Ok so hours of trial and error I kept getting the error “unable to get deployment status.” Like the OP is describing.  I followed harrymc’s instructions but still wasn’t working.  Turns out my DNS needed an A and PTR record for the new vCenter to get past step 2 of the installation.  Now it is all good :-)

Comment: missing DNS and PTR for vCenter was the cause of the OP error in my case too. Adding those records and reinstalling vCenter has fixed the issue.